# can someone explain to me how to make a search method for a general tree class? in java

Tags: java, search, methods, tree

I found for binary trees and other types of trees.

I dont understand how to make a search method for a general tree.

What I came up with is something like this

```
comparable Search(GeneralTreeNode node, comparable key){
if(node != root){
  if(root.getChildren().contains(node))
  return node.key;
  }
else return // I dont know what to do next ???????
 }
}
```

My class has root as my general tree node and key as a comparable object.

Comment: each node has children as array list

Answer (score 0):

Important here is to understand what type of tree you want to search and which method you want to search it with.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

The main two types are;
1. Depth-first
2. Breath-first

More about this can also be found at:
http://www.javabeat.net/binary-search-tree-traversal-java/

Comment: how do i search in a general tree not binary? using both Depth-first and Breath-first does search for general tree work the same way?

Comment: Yes, binary is a special type of tree only having two childs per node.
For more information, watch this MIT lecture about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jry5-82I68

Comment: Thank you very much for the sources they helped me a lot. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, please select my answer as the answer to your question so it's marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about BFS & DFS algorithms

[DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Both of them are probably the most famouse Graph (and Tree) search algorithms